# I use UITableViewSource I want change this code to loop

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have UITableViewSource I want loop data  from web service I added to labels to UITableViewSource

Fisrt lable :    Lblqut.text 
Second Lable :  LblAnswer.text

I want Display Data to  UITableViewSource  in labels. Now every thins is ok but I get issue in this line employees.Add(item.Answ, item.AskID)

```
  var employees = new List<Employee>
 {
 new Employee
 {
     Fullname="ahmed",
     Department="Finance"
 }

 };
 listVStud.Source = new EmployeesTVS(employees);
```

I get issue in my code

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
            foreach (var item in e.Result)
            {
                employees.Add(item.Answ, item.AskID);
            }

            listVStud.Source = new EmployeesTVS(employees);
```

this Class  EmployeesTVS

```
 class EmployeesTVS : UITableViewSource
 {
      List<Employee> employees;

    public EmployeesTVS(List<Employee> employees)
    {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

        var cell = (EmployeeCell) tableView.DequeueReusableCell("Cell_id", indexPath);

        var employee = employees[indexPath.Row];
        cell.updatecell(employee);

        return cell;

    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return employees.Count;
    }
}
```

this Class Employee

```
 class Employee
{

    public string Fullname
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public string Department
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

this class EmployeeCell

```
public partial class EmployeeCell : UITableViewCell
{
    public EmployeeCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {


    }

    internal void updatecell(Employee employee)
    {

        Lblqut.Text = employee.Fullname;
        LblAnswer.Text = employee.Department;


    }
}
```

Comment: employees is a list, have no method like Add(x,x);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this instead:

```
employees.Add(new Employee { Fullname = item.Answ, Department = item.AskID });
```